# Graphing a line with 2 x axes

Tags: plot, gnuplot, axes

I'm measuring performance of a program which calls lots of subroutines. I've output the cpu performance over time, and the time at which each subroutine is called.

I'd like to graph this in order to visualize where each performance hit is, which subroutine it was in, and what time it was.

So I think that the best way (probably) to graph this would be with a time x axis, and a subroutine x axis. Is this possible with gnuplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sure, something like this (depending on how your data ia arranged of course..)

```
  plot 'file' using 1:2 axes x1y1 , 'file' using 3:4 axes x2y1
```

see the manual under set x1axes for options you'll likely want such as nomirror..